# NLog 5.2.4 - Unable to filter out Microsoft.Extensions.Http logs

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I am using NLog for logging and I keep getting these logs in my logfile:

```
2023-09-07 11:45:10.4748 Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler+Log.RequestPipelineStart - 1 - Start processing HTTP request POST http://localhost:3000/api/agent/v3/login

2023-09-07 11:45:10.4748 Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler+Log.RequestPipelineStart - 1 - Request Headers:
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I do not want to log these events when they occur.

My current `Nlog.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true" throwExceptions="false">
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    </extensions>
    <targets async="true">
        <target xsi:type="File" name="default"
                layout="${longdate} ${callsite:className=true} - ${threadid} - ${message}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION\: ${exception:format=ToString}}"
                fileName="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}\mystuff\Log\test\mystuff.log"
                keepFileOpen="false"
                archiveFileName="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}\mystuff\Log\test\Archive\mystuff_{#}.log"
                archiveNumbering="Date" archiveEvery="Day"
                maxArchiveFiles="60" />

        <target xsi:type="File" name="HostLog"
                layout="${longdate} ${callsite:className=true - ${threadid} - ${message}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION\: ${exception:format=ToString}}"
                fileName="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}\mystuff\Log\HostLog\hostlog.log"
                keepFileOpen="false"
                archiveFileName="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}\mystuff\Log\HostLog\Archive\hostlog{#}.log"
                archiveNumbering="Date"
                archiveEvery="Day"
                maxArchiveFiles="5" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <!-- Nlog log levels are:  Trace, Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal.-->
        <logger name="MyStuff.HostedServices.*" writeTo="HostLog" minlevel="Debug" final="true"/>
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" writeTo="HostLog" minlevel="Error" final="true" />

        <!-- Set black hole for microsoft logs -->
        <logger name="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.*" finalMinLevel="Info" /> 
        <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime*" finalMinLevel="Info" />
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" maxLevel="Warn" final="true" />
        <logger name="MyStuff.HostedServices.*" minlevel="Trace" maxLevel="Trace" final="true"/>
        <logger name="MyStuff.Services.*" minlevel="Trace" maxLevel="Trace" final="true" />
        <!-- End the black hole settings-->

        <logger name="*" writeTo="default" minlevel="Trace" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I have manipulated this config file many times and I still cannot get rid of those 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http' logs.  I am using NLog 5.2.4. This is slowly driving me mad.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to suppress Microsoft logs with NLog for API calls using HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479689/unable-to-suppress-microsoft-logs-with-nlog-for-api-calls-using-httpclient)

Comment: I can see that you are using the expensive `${callsite}` in your Layout, which is different from `${logger}`. NLog Logging Rules performs filtering based on Logger-name. I recommend that you update the Layout to use `${logger}` (instead of `${callsite}`) and include sample of the unwanted target-ouput in your question.  See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Rules-FinalMinLevel

Comment: Maybe duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76205628/193178

Comment: Akseli I am using NLog 5.2.4 so it shouldn't need any logging settings set in the a appsettings.json file.

Comment: What is the difference between callsite and logger?  I did change it to logger and I am still seeing the same issue.  I am starting to think this might be a NLog or Microsoft bug.  I am trying to use filter and filter out any log text that contains Microsoft.Extensions but I am still not having any luck in doing it that way.

Comment: I was incorrect.  If I use the logger instead of the callsite then rules start working as expected.  But before I use this fix, I need to know the difference between callsite and logging.  The documentation on these two items seem to be severely lacking.

Comment: @ashlar64 [${callsite}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer) "scans the callstack and output the stackframe just before the NLog Logger takes over". And [${logger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logger-layout-renderer) "Renders name of the Logger that produced the LogEvent".